# Object of class charts could not be converted to string

Tags: php

I have written a class for which the constructor function has 3 arguments. In some function of the class I have to query from db like this
$profit_row->operating_profit.

now instead of writing operating_profit, I want to pass it as a variable to the constructor of the class. So my whole variable becomes
$profit_row->$this->num
where $this->num is initialized in the constructor.

When I do this I get the following error. How to go about this. 
Object of class charts could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
$profit_row->{$this->num}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$profit_row->{$this->num}
```

you have a precedence problem.